# Hovertool Bokeh "Cannot read property"

Tags: hover, bokeh

My problem is that in Chrome, when I have my cursor on my histogram hover my data, I have this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0'
```

There is my code :

```
hist, edges = np.histogram(data,bins=3000)

plot = quad(
    top=hist,
    bottom=0,
    left=edges[:-1],
    right=edges[1:],
    fill_color="#036564",
    line_color="#033649",
    tools="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset, hover",
    x_range=[-0.5,3.5],
    plot_width=1100, 
    title="",
)

hover = plot.select(dict(type=HoverTool))
hover.tooltips = [('index','$index')]

resources = Resources("inline")

plot_script, plot_div = components(plot, resources)

html_script = mark_safe(encode_utf8(plot_script))
html_div = mark_safe(encode_utf8(plot_div))

figure()

return html_script, html_div
```

"data" is a array like this :

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.24,1,1.32,1,2,3]
```

I tried to add a "source" in the quad, changed the figure, changed my code for the one on the documentation but I still have my error.

For information, everything is working very well, except the hover tool.

Indeed, in the "hover box" I want another informations then just "index", but it's just for testing.

Thanks for reading !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I missed this earlier. You have uncovered a small bug with the hover tool that is particular to `quad` glyphs. In the mean time you can add `hover.snap_to_data = False` to get it to work.

Here is a GH issue you can track for the full solution:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/1644

A fix should be in the 0.7.1 release next Monday.

Also BTW, you are using a deprecated API. You should now write code like:

```
p = figure(...)
p.quad(...)
```